# Ignore wp-config.php WordPress not working

Tags: git, phpstorm, gitignore

I have tried a lot to gitignore `wp-config.php` on a fresh installation of WordPress, not fresh installation also but none of them has worked. I am using PhpStorm.

Does anyone have an idea?

Please note that I have used `rm -- cached` and all know solutions.

the commands tested

```
git rm --cached wp-config.php

add file to .gitignore
```

Comment: "*…none of them has worked…*" What does it mean? "*`rm -- cached`*" Wrong syntax, the correct syntax is different.

Comment: lol , it is not question of syntax , it is not working

Comment: It is not working because of the wrong syntax.

Comment: I have tested correct syntax , it is not working

Comment: What exactly is not working? [edit] the question and add what commands have you tried, what was the output and what do you expect instead.

Comment: @asquestion8 You fixed?

Comment: no did not work , i retry and inform you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that wp-config.php is already in the repository!? You have to remove them with:

1. Add to your .gitignore file wp-config.php
2. Remove from repository with: `git rm --cached .`
3. Then `git add .` and commit with `git commit -m "add wpConfigPhp to gitignore"`